# Pico de conexões MySQL + Bad Gateway nginx php

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, amazon-aws

Tenho na AWS:

> RDS m5.xlarge
>   MySQL 5.6
>
> EC2 t2.small
>   NGINX + PHP 7.1

De uma maneira intermitente, meu MySQL está recebe um pico de conexões, 20 para ser mais exato. E Toda vez que isso acontece, aparece "Bad Gateway" no NGINX.

1. De acordo com o tipo de RDS, 20 conexões não seria pouco para ela ficar inacessível?
2. Como posso investigar melhor o motivo desse pico de conexões?

Comment: Seja mais específico na pergunta pois com o NGINX de erro 502 Bad Gateway são 7 variações:`502 Bad Gateway`, `HTTP Error 502 - Bad Gateway`, `502 Service Temporarily Overloaded`, `Error 502`, `502 Proxy Error`, `HTTP 502`, `502 Bad Gateway NGINX`, Também o conteúdo do arquivo `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques 502 Bad Gateway, [error] 18088#0: *7213182 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

Comment: tem esse outro log minutos antes: 18088#0: *7207485 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream,

Comment: Isso acontece porque o upstream leva muito tempo para atender a requisição. Pode ser que o recurso em questão tome muito tempo de processamento para ser atendido em geral mais tempo do que o time out do servidor o que faz disparar o erro 502.
O que você pode fazer é aumentar o time out nas configurações, por exemplo `proxy_read_timeout 900;` faz o servidor aguardar 15min antes de decidir que um recurso está indisponível.

Comment: Vale ressaltar que apenas aumentar o timeout é apenas um workaround, o certo seria você instalar alguma ferramenta de profiling e descobrir o que está causando o timeout e trabalhar em melhorar a performance deste ponto ao invés de apenas aumentar o timeout.

Comment: @AugustoVasques esse log ajuda em algo? 
[05-Jul-2019 15:25:18] 
WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (8), consider raising it.  

pm                        = dynamic
pm.max_children           = 8
pm.start_servers          = 3
pm.min_spare_servers      = 3
pm.max_spare_servers      = 6
pm.max_requests           = 200
;pm.status_path           = /status
;ping.path                = /ping
;ping.response            = pong
;pm.process_idle_timeout  = 10s;

request_terminate_timeout = 200s
request_slowlog_timeout   = 60s

Comment: Ajuda muito. Ele diz que o PHP-FPM permite até oito processos filhos e ele bateu esse limite. Dependendo da versão do PHP-FPM você tem que encontrar o arquivo `php-fpm.conf` ou `www.conf` e aumente o `pm.max_children` lembrando que para o valor máximo para `pm.max_children = RAM dedicada ao servidor / Tamanho máximo permitido a um processo`. **PS: Caso você aumente memória e tempo dedicados e ainda continue a dar o mesmo erro considere a possibilidade de seu programa em php estar em loop.**

Comment: @AugustoVasques show! mudei o pm.max_children de 8 para 16. apenas para conhecimento o é memory_limit = 128M. aparentemente não gerou mais o log disso. somente um outro começou aparecer:  NOTICE: [pool www] child 9430 exited with code 0 after 673.434081 seconds from start

Comment: @Claytinho, ` code 0` significa que está ok, mas deve estar logando porque ainda está próximo ao tempo limite, mas não o passou. Leve isso para o resto da vida, **O Log é o seu melhor amigo e nunca esqueça dele.**